# Kuebrnetes pods get wrong DNS nameserver IP address on minikube

Tags: dns, kubernetes, minikube, kube-dns

I have faced an issue with resolving services host between with kubernetes on minikube. 
So from the inside the pod I cannot `wget web-server:8081/endpoint`. But I can access the same server directly by IP address like this `wget 10.0.0.81:8081/endpoint`.

After troubleshooting the issue I have found that inside of the pod `/etc/resolve.conf` file the `nameserver` is set to `10.96.0.10`. Here is how it looks:

```
nameserver 10.96.0.10
search default.svc.cluster.local svc.cluster.local cluster.local
options ndots:5
```

When the Cluster IP of `kube-dns` service is `10.0.0.10`.
After changing manually the nameserver on the pod to `10.0.0.10` I cat do `wget web-server:8081/endpoint`.

Why is it set to the wrong IP address and how fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I updated `minikube` without `minikube delete`.
After `minikube delete` and `minikube start` the DNS service is getting the IP address `10.96.0.10` the same as is set in the pod's `/etc/resolve.conf`.

Comment: I have a similar issue but with a 172 subnet, and delete/start hasn't resolved the issue. The 172 subnet seems to be coming from default docker configuration, whereas the 10.96 stuff from minikube. Is minikube's docker misconfigured?

Comment: @sholsapp what is the version of k8s that you are using? Is container that gets 172 subnet your own container? The k8s should be responsible for network configuration in this case